# what is pl/sql varchar2 type in java?

Tags: java, plsql

1. Is there a varchar2 variable type in java? Need to convert the following varchar2 variable in pl/sql into java.
2. If yes which library is needed? (e.g. import ...)

e.g:

a) in pl/sql:

```
SE      VARCHAR2(5) := 0;
FIME    VARCHAR2(100) := P_FIME;
```

b) in java (is this correct? or need to replace varchar2 with string[]?):

```
varchar2 SE[5] = 0;
varchar2 FIME[100] = P_FIME;
```

Comment: ok Thanks Alexis Pigeon. I'm completely new to java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`VARCHAR2` in Java is regular String

Answer (score 2):

`VARCHAR2` in java could be `String` or `char[]`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use String to represent VARCHAR2 in java

Answer (score 1):

Varchar2 can be used as normal String in java for more info about `jdbc data types` [refer here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-data-types.htm)